# Is this Overloaded TASK Method?

Tags: c#, rss, feed, overloading, c#-5.0

I was reading through this code , which is dealing with feeds RSS & Atom feeds it's simply as it looks returns a feedsdata objects bu using the feeds datasource class  :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Web.Syndication;

namespace WindowsBlogReader
{
    // FeedData
    // Holds info for a single blog feed, including a list of blog posts (FeedItem).
    public class FeedData
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime PubDate { get; set; }

        private List<FeedItem> _Items = new List<FeedItem>();
        public List<FeedItem> Items
        {
            get
            {
                return this._Items;
            }
        }
    }

    // FeedItem
    // Holds info for a single blog post.
    public class FeedItem
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public DateTime PubDate { get; set; }
        public Uri Link { get; set; }
    }

    // FeedDataSource
    // Holds a collection of blog feeds (FeedData), and contains methods needed to
    // retreive the feeds.
    public class FeedDataSource
    {
        private ObservableCollection<FeedData> _Feeds = new ObservableCollection<FeedData>();
        public ObservableCollection<FeedData> Feeds
        {
            get
            {
                return this._Feeds;
            }
        }

        public async Task GetFeedsAsync()
        {
            Task<FeedData> feed1 =
                GetFeedAsync("http://blogs.windows.com/skydrive/b/skydrive/atom.aspx");
            Task<FeedData> feed2 =
                GetFeedAsync("http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/windowsexperience/atom.aspx");
            Task<FeedData> feed3 =
                GetFeedAsync("http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/extremewindows/atom.aspx");
            Task<FeedData> feed4 =
                GetFeedAsync("http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/business/atom.aspx");
            Task<FeedData> feed5 =
                GetFeedAsync("http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/bloggingwindows/atom.aspx");
            Task<FeedData> feed6 =
                GetFeedAsync("http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/windowssecurity/atom.aspx");
            Task<FeedData> feed7 =
                GetFeedAsync("http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/springboard/atom.aspx");
            Task<FeedData> feed8 =
                GetFeedAsync("http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/windowshomeserver/atom.aspx");
            // There is no Atom feed for this blog, so use the RSS feed.
            Task<FeedData> feed9 =
                GetFeedAsync("http://blogs.windows.com/windows_live/b/windowslive/rss.aspx");
            Task<FeedData> feed10 =
                GetFeedAsync("http://blogs.windows.com/windows_live/b/developer/atom.aspx");
            Task<FeedData> feed11 =
                GetFeedAsync("http://blogs.windows.com/ie/b/ie/atom.aspx");
            Task<FeedData> feed12 =
                GetFeedAsync("http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/atom.aspx");
            Task<FeedData> feed13 =
                GetFeedAsync("http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wmdev/atom.aspx");
            Task<FeedData> feed14 =
                GetFeedAsync("http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/windowsphone/atom.aspx");

            this.Feeds.Add(await feed1);
            this.Feeds.Add(await feed2);
            this.Feeds.Add(await feed3);
            this.Feeds.Add(await feed4);
            this.Feeds.Add(await feed5);
            this.Feeds.Add(await feed6);
            this.Feeds.Add(await feed7);
            this.Feeds.Add(await feed8);
            this.Feeds.Add(await feed9);
            this.Feeds.Add(await feed10);
            this.Feeds.Add(await feed11);
            this.Feeds.Add(await feed12);
            this.Feeds.Add(await feed13);
            this.Feeds.Add(await feed14);
        }

        private async Task<FeedData> GetFeedAsync(string feedUriString)
        {
            Windows.Web.Syndication.SyndicationClient client = new SyndicationClient();
            Uri feedUri = new Uri(feedUriString);

            try
            {
                SyndicationFeed feed = await client.RetrieveFeedAsync(feedUri);

                // This code is executed after RetrieveFeedAsync returns the SyndicationFeed.
                // Process the feed and copy the data you want into the FeedData and FeedItem classes.
                FeedData feedData = new FeedData();

                if (feed.Title != null && feed.Title.Text != null)
                {
                    feedData.Title = feed.Title.Text;
                }
                if (feed.Subtitle != null && feed.Subtitle.Text != null)
                {
                    feedData.Description = feed.Subtitle.Text;
                }
                if (feed.Items != null && feed.Items.Count > 0)
                {
                    // Use the date of the latest post as the last updated date.
                    feedData.PubDate = feed.Items[0].PublishedDate.DateTime;

                    foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items)
                    {
                        FeedItem feedItem = new FeedItem();
                        if (item.Title != null && item.Title.Text != null)
                        {
                            feedItem.Title = item.Title.Text;
                        }
                        if (item.PublishedDate != null)
                        {
                            feedItem.PubDate = item.PublishedDate.DateTime;
                        }
                        if (item.Authors != null && item.Authors.Count > 0)
                        {
                            feedItem.Author = item.Authors[0].Name.ToString();
                        }
                        // Handle the differences between RSS and Atom feeds.
                        if (feed.SourceFormat == SyndicationFormat.Atom10)
                        {
                            if (item.Content != null && item.Content.Text != null)
                            {
                                feedItem.Content = item.Content.Text;
                            }
                            if (item.Id != null)
                            {
                                feedItem.Link = new Uri(item.Id);
                            }
                        }
                        else if (feed.SourceFormat == SyndicationFormat.Rss20)
                        {
                            if (item.Summary != null && item.Summary.Text != null)
                            {
                                feedItem.Content = item.Summary.Text;
                            }
                            if (item.Links != null && item.Links.Count > 0)
                            {
                                feedItem.Link = item.Links[0].Uri;
                            }
                        }
                        feedData.Items.Add(feedItem);
                    }    
                }
                return feedData;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Returns the feed that has the specified title.
        public static FeedData GetFeed(string title)
        {
            // Simple linear search is acceptable for small data sets
            var _feedDataSource = App.Current.Resources["feedDataSource"] as FeedDataSource;

            var matches = _feedDataSource.Feeds.Where((feed) => feed != null && feed.Title.Equals(title));
            if (matches.Count() == 1) return matches.First();
            return null;
        }

        // Returns the post that has the specified title.
        public static FeedItem GetItem(string uniqueId)
        {
            // Simple linear search is acceptable for small data sets
            var _feedDataSource = App.Current.Resources["feedDataSource"] as FeedDataSource;

            var matches = _feedDataSource.Feeds
                .Where(group => group != null)
                .SelectMany(group => group.Items).Where((item) => item.Title.Equals(uniqueId));
            if (matches.Count() == 1) return matches.First();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

My question is about the TASK Methods:

1. `public async Task GetFeedsAsync()`
2. `private async Task<FeedData> GetFeedAsync(string feedUriString)`

It's clear that the 2nd method is overloaded from the first one, now what I want to make clear here is this 2 implementations of the way that I can deal with the datasource, to make my question more clear: does it mean that we can use either the first TASK method to provide the feed uri or use the 2nd TASK Method, and I can choose to use one of them?

I hope that I explained my misunderstanding very well.

Comment: Don't swallow exceptions.

Comment: `it's clear that the 2nd method is overloaded from the first one` ... wrong

Comment: Consider removing the redundancy in `GetFeedsAsync`. Imagine that you have to maintain this later...

Comment: `this.Feeds.AddRange(await Task.WhenAll(urls.Select(GetFeedAsync))`

Answer (score 1):

Those are two completely unrelated methods, except that one of them calls the other one.

You can call whichever one you like, depending on what you're trying to do

Comment: Ummm , I don't understand the 2 methods here have the same name but they deferent parameters isn't that the rules for overloading methods , and may you please tell me where , in which line the first method calls the 2nd one ?

Comment: Ok now it becomes clear that the 2 methods are deferent , but I sill can't find out where does one of the methods call the another one can you please highlight the line where this call happen and i'll be thankful

Comment: @AlbihanyAden Did you overlook the dozen or so lines that start with `GetFeedAsync()`?

Comment: I Mistakenly missed that "s" between the 2 methods GetFeedsAsync() != GetFeedAsync() , everything becomes clear now thank you all

Answer (score 0):

No, the 1st method is Get**Feeds**Async while the 2nd method is Get**Feed**Async().
They are clearly 2 different methods.

Get**Feeds**Async method calls the Get**Feed**Async() method 14 times, each time passing a web-link to that feed. The  Get**Feed**Async() method then downloads the feed data and parses the xml retrieved to extract valuable info. like title, published date, author,etc